# Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1: "Last Write Wins"

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-2016-express

I would like some help finding any (C#) example of Sync Framework 2.1 using the "Last Write Wins" conflict resolution style. I followed the example MS put out, and my provisioning/sync works just fine, my issue is that I cannot use UploadAndDownload/DownloadAndUpload/Download/Upload for my situation. I need the site that has written the record LAST to have precedent. Can anyone point to depiction of the Framework doing that? I should note my dbo.TABLE_tracking last_change_datetime column is being populated throughout every change made in the database (respectively... obviously "TABLE" is just a generic example), and so I would hope that once I see find how to enable last write wins that I would experience the desired behavior.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/synchronization/sync-framework-2.1/bb725997(v=sql.110)

Comment: Unfortunately this is the same documentation as I have relied on. How this can appear to be close to my request I cannot understand. Can anyone else point to an example of "last write wins" in action?

Comment: If you can switch to another sync framework, my advice would be to give a try to Dotmim.Sync : https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync  (doc : https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/)